# How does Feign Death stored in a Glyph of Warding work?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, traps

[Feign Death](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feign-death) seems to be a valid spell to be stored as a spell glyph in a [Glyph of Warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding). It targets only a single creature and is a 3rd level spell. However, what I am concerned with is the fact that Feign Death requires a *willing* target:

Can the creature that triggers the glyph choose not to be affected by the spell because they are not willing to or is the glyph overriding that requirement by making the spell forcefully target that creature?

Comment: I've asked this as a separate question here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141502/how-does-a-spell-glyph-work-when-the-stored-spell-has-a-range-of-touch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a creature can choose to be unwilling when a spellcaster touches them, they can be unwilling if a glyph touches them.

If the creature is unwilling to be the subject of the spell, he is an invalid target. Nevertheless the spell will target them. Xanathar's Guide has this to say on invalid targets, on pages 85-86:

> But what happens if a spell targets something that isn't a valid
>   target? [..] If you cast a spell on someone or something that can't
>   be affected by the spell, nothing happens to that target but if you used a spell slot to cast the spell, the slot is still expended.

So an unwilling target will be unaffected, and the glyph will be spent.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that that rule is indeed presented as an entirely optional rule so DM's not using XGE optional rules may actually rule differently and still be acting in RAW.